# Where am I going wrong with this function to find expressions that add to a sum using number 1 - 9 using operations (+, -, and concat)?

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

Could someone help fix this bug? Trying to write a function that generations a list of mathematical expressions that evaluate to 100 with numbers 1 through 9 through the use addition, subtraction, or concatenation? I got add and sub branches working. When I pull in the path for concatenation, it only works on some test cases? Thanks in advance. Below is my code.

For my test cases with numbers 1-9 and a sum of 100, some expression are wrong and some are missing. Here is my output:

- 1 + 2 + 3 + -4 + 5 + 6 + 78 + 9
- 1 + 2 + 34 + -5 + 67 + -8 + 9
- 1 + 23 + -4 + 5 + 6 + 78 + -9
- 1 + 23 + -4 + 56 + 7 + 8 + 9
- 12 + 3 + 4 + 5 + -6 + -7 + 89
- 12 + 3 + -4 + 5 + 67 + 8 + 9
- 12 + -3 + -4 + 5 + -6 + 7 + 89
- 123 + -4 + -5 + -6 + -7 + 8 + -9
- 123 + -35 + 6 + 7 + 8 + -9

  ```
  package domain;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class ExpressionFinder {

   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

   public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getExpressions(int sum, int[] operands){

     ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> expressions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
     ArrayList<Integer> sourceExpression = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     sourceExpression.add(operands[0]);
     findExpressions(expressions, sourceExpression, sum - operands[0], operands, 1);
     return expressions;
   }

   public static String getReadableExpression(List<Integer> operands){
      List<String> exp = new ArrayList<String>(operands.size());

      for(Integer op : operands)
         exp.add(String.valueOf(op));

      return String.join(" + ", exp);
   }

  private void findExpressions(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> expressions, ArrayList<Integer> currentExpression, int sum, int[] operands, int current){

     if(current == operands.length){
         if(sum == 0)
             expressions.add(new ArrayList<>(currentExpression));
         return;
    }

   currentExpression.add(operands[current]);
   findExpressions( expressions, currentExpression, sum - currentExpression.get(currentExpression.size() - 1), operands, current + 1);
   currentExpression.remove(currentExpression.size() - 1);

   currentExpression.add(-operands[current]);
   findExpressions( expressions, currentExpression, sum - currentExpression.get(currentExpression.size() - 1), operands, current + 1);
   currentExpression.remove(currentExpression.size() - 1);


   //System.out.println(currentExpression);
   int last = currentExpression.get(currentExpression.size() - 1);
   currentExpression.set(currentExpression.size() - 1, last * 10 + operands[current]);
   findExpressions( expressions, currentExpression, sum + last - ((last * 10 + operands[current])), operands, current + 1);
  }



  public static void main(String[] args){

      ExpressionFinder expFinder = new ExpressionFinder();
      ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> expressions = expFinder.getExpressions(100, new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});


       for(ArrayList<Integer> expression : expressions)
      System.out.println(ExpressionFinder.getReadableExpression(expression));
       }
     }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more interesting solution to this problem. You can use addition in `ternary` base. Why ternary ? because you have 3 operation: `+`, `-`, `concat`

```
void ternaryIncrement(int n) {
    int[] a = new int[n - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < Math.pow(3, n - 1) - 1; i++) {
        a[0]++;
        for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if(a[j] > 2) {
                a[j] = 0;
                a[j + 1]++;
            }
        }
        // Build your expression base on array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

For input `n = 3` you will get this output :

```
[1, 0]
[2, 0]
[0, 1]
[1, 1]
[2, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
```

Notice that for `n` numbers you will have an operation between every number, so `n - 1` operations. So you will put operations accordingly. For example if it's 0 you concat, if it's 1 you add and for 2 you substract.

Comment: if the 35 in his output is valid, that would mean four possibilities: add, subtract, concat, or omit.